# Rename an Azure ML experiment

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

How do you rename an Azure ML Experiment? I cannot see any property field you can set. All I can find is Save As something else, then delete the original experiment.

When I Save for the first time, it doesn't ask me for a name, it just saves it with a standard date.

Am I missing something simple and obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the cursor on the name text when an experiment is open, and edit away.